# Xiaomi phones battery compatibility

Tags: battery, hardware

Xiaomi phones have several batteries, for example, `BM35`, `BM21`, `BN43`, and etc.

I'd like to know the compatibility of those batteries, for example, if `BM35` has the same pin and size as `BM21` something like that.

I have this [Xiaomi Redmi Note 4x](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_note_4x-8580.php) it's kinda old but still working and the battery is now needed to be replaced because it's already draining fast. Instead of using the `BM43` which is the current battery of it, I'd like to purchase a different model with a higher capacity for example the `BN62`.

If I only know the pin type and the size of those batteries, it will be easy for me to upgrade and replace them.

Comment: Actually, that will be hard but can be done. You may be able to find the dimensions or size of the battery but you will be having a hard time to figure the pin type of it. I tried searching for the specifications of BM43, I only get the dimensions and capacity.